Reverse System Solving: Finding α and β in Geometric Progression Equations
The numbers  $t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4$ are the first four terms of a geometric progression. It is known that  $t_1$ and $t_2$ are the roots of the equation $t^{2} + 2\alpha t + 4 = 0$, and $t_3$ and $t_4$ are the roots of the equation $2t^{2} + \beta t + 32 = 0$. Find $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
I have repeatedly tried to solve this problem, but without success. I performed transformations for each term according to the formula of the N-th term, then made a system, but when solving it I started to get odd degrees and the answer, even when calculated on a calculator, looked strange.

Since $t_1$ and $t_2$ are roots of $t^2+2\alpha t+4=0$ we have $t_1 t_2 =4$
Since $t_3$ and $t_4$ are roots of $2t^2+\beta t+32=0$ we have $t_3 t_4=16$
Now, since the terms are in a geometric progression, we can write $t_1=a,t_2=ar,t_3=ar^2,t_4=ar^3$.
This gives $a\times ar=4$ and $ar^2 \times ar^3=16$
Division then gives $r^4=2$ and so $r=\sqrt{2}$ (Assuming $r>0$ and real which can be checked later with the original equations).
Substituting back into $a^2r=4$ this gives $a=2^\frac{3}{4}$
Using Vieta's formulas again, $t_1+t_2=-2\alpha$
So $-2\alpha=2^\frac{3}{4}(1+\sqrt{2})$ and therefore $\alpha=-2^\frac{-1}{4}(1+\sqrt{2})$ which can also be written $\alpha=-2^\frac{-1}{4}-2^\frac{1}{4}$.
For $\beta$ we use the second equation and note that $t_3+t_4=\frac{-\beta}{2}$
So $\beta=-2a(r^2+r^3)=-2^\frac{7}{4}(2^1+2^\frac{3}{2})$
$\beta=-2^\frac{11}{4}-2^\frac{13}{4}$.
The final answers may not be pretty, but the question itself is nice. Thanks for sharing it.
